# Move the splitter in Visual Studio IDE with shortcut

Tags: visual-studio

Is it possible to move the splitter in Visual Studio IDE with keyboard shortcut.

I don't like to use the mouse. I want to be able to make the make tool windows small and larger by moving the splitter.

[image]

Comment: This isn't really a programming question, but I'd still like to ask "what have you tried?" 
A quick search led me to this page: http://visualstudioshortcuts.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like the idea as well, but I don't think it available in VS now. There are several options to achieve your purpose: Switch and resize between windows.

1. Make `Output` window (or any window you interested) auto hide and make this window much bigger than default size, so that you can see a bigger `Output` window when you need it.
2. Create different window layouts with different window size. Check `Switch between the layouts` at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4k7zyeba.aspx.

None of these two options can resize window freely. They can only switch to fixed size. Or submit your idea at http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio to get implemented in next VS release.